# How to correctly type a function that maps object values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapping

I have a function that given an object and a lookup map or a mapping function, it returns another object with the values mapped as follows:

```js
function mapValues(object, mapping) {
    const result = {}

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        if (typeof mapping === 'function') {
            result[key] = mapping(value);

            continue;
        }

        result[key] = typeof value === 'string' || typeof value == 'number' || typeof value == 'symbol'
            ? mapping[value]
            : value;
    }

    return result;
}


// Return type: {foo: 1, bar: null, baz: undefined}
console.log(mapValues({foo: 'a', bar: 'b', baz: undefined}, {a: 1, b: null}));

// Return type: {foo: number, bar: number, baz: number}
console.log(mapValues({foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}, value => value + 1));
```

How to type this function signature and overloadings so that the return type matches the previous scenarios?

Comment: I like your function! :)

Comment: `Object.keys`, `Object.entries`, etc. don't return the specific types.  This is by design because an object of type `SomeType` can include more properties than just what is defined in `SomeType`.  We can't know the type of any excess properties, so be aware that any typed mapper should be used carefully as the result type might not actually be correct.

Comment: For the function version: `function mapValues<O extends Record<string, any>, M>(object: O, mapping: (value: ValueOf<O>) => M): Record<keyof O, M>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd probably give `mapValues()` an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function type, since the two ways to call it are distinct.  Keep in mind that these are *approximate* typings and there may be edge cases.

--

First, the easy one: the call signature when the second argument is a function:

```
function mapValues<T extends object, U>(
    object: T,
    mappingFn: (x: T[keyof T]) => U
): { [K in keyof T]: U };
```

Here we are just saying that `mapValues()` will take an `object` of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type `T` and a `mappingFn` which is itself a function that takes an argument of type `T[keyof T]` (all *known* property value types of `T`) and returns a value of generic type `U`.  The return type of the whole function is an object type with the same keys as `T` but whose values are of type `U`.

---

Now for the hard one: the call signature when the second argument is an object:

```
function mapValues<
    T extends Record<keyof T, N>,
    M extends object,
    N extends PropertyKey | null | undefined | {}
>(
    object: T, mappingObj: M
): { [K in keyof T]:
        T[K] extends PropertyKey ? T[K] extends keyof M ? M[T[K]] : unknown : T[K]
    };
```

Let's pretend that `N` isn't there for now.  This function takes an `object` of some object type `T`, and a `mappingObj` of some object type `M`, and returns a new object.  For each key `K` in `T`, the return value also has a key `K`, and its property type is calculated depending on whether the property of `T` at key `K` (`T[K]`) is itself a keylike thing (`string` or `number` or `symbol`, also known as `PropertyKey`):

- If `T[K]` *is* keylike, we will try to look up that key in `M`. If we find it, then we will return the same property take at that key, `M[T[K]]`.  If we *don't* find it, then frankly we have no idea what the output property will be.  It would be nice to claim it should be `undefined`, but this can happen either because we don't know the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) of `T[K]`, or because `object` happens to have a property at key `T[K]` but `T` does not (object types in TypeScript are *open*, not *closed*, so objects may have more properties than the compiler knows about).  So the safest thing to return here is `unknown`.
- If `T[K]` is *not* keylike, then we will just return `T[K]`.

That all makes sense.  The wrinkle with `N` is that if I left out `N` and just wrote `T extends object`, the compiler would not realize that it had to pay attention to the *literal* values of the properties of `object`.  It would naturally infer `{foo: "a", bar: "b"}` to be of type `{foo: string, bar: string}`.  If you want it to keep track of `"a"` and `"b`", you need to give it a hint.  By having `T extends Record<keyof T, N>` where `N` is a very wide type that includes `PropertyKey`, the compiler takes that as a hint that we care about the literal types of each property of `T`.  It's ugly/crazy.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a feature request to make this less crazy/ugly in the future.

Whew!

---

For the implementation, you could try to be strict, but I'll just annotate things as `any` and assume that the burden of providing type safety is on the implementer and not the compiler, which probably can't rise to the task for such a complicated conditional generic type signature anyway:

```
function mapValues(object: any, mapping: any) {
    const result: any = {}
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        if (typeof mapping === 'function') {
            result[key] = mapping(value);
            continue;
        }
        console.log(key, value)
        result[key] = typeof value === 'string' || typeof value == 'number' || typeof value == 'symbol'
            ? mapping[value]
            : value;
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

Let's test it on your examples:

```
const mappedFromFn = mapValues({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }, value => value + 1);
/* const mappedFromFn: {
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
    baz: number;
} */
console.log(mappedFromFn); // {foo: 2, bar: 3, baz: 4 }
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers that the unannotated `value` parameter in the callback function will be of type `number`, and that `mappedFromFn` will have `number` properties at the `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` keys.  This turns out to be true at runtime also.

And this one:

```
const mappedFromObj = mapValues({ foo: 'a', bar: 'b', baz: undefined }, { a: 1, b: null });
/* const mappedFromObj: {
    foo: number;
    bar: null;
    baz: undefined;
} */
console.log(mappedFromObj); // {foo: 1, bar: null, baz: undefined }
```

Also looks good.  the compiler keeps track of the `"a"` and `"b`" in `object`, and maps the `foo` property to `number` and the `bar` property to `null`, while leaving the `baz` property alone.  This turns out to be true at runtime also.

---

As I said, there may well be edge cases to this, so you'll have to test to see that it works for your use cases, and if not, you might need to tweak things to do what you consider reasonable.  But this is the general approach I'd follow.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcBqqA2ICmAzgDwAqi+AHlPmACaGJwBGAVvtADSICqAfAAoAsAChE4pmw5QAXIlKdRElBnQwwAcwBiYOQMpzSAbQDW+AJ5xg8gLoBKRAF4+vUXbkBvREYDSidYhmltakNnI8iAC+ANyioqCQsAgqWLgEJEoS5FQ09IwAShxwAE50xEFW8twAcnyKYhIAshTUtAyS7FyZ4tUtue0ACsVw6PjFUOY+FogAPohgIDg4s4jgdPjA6vh0Kx6RooLdHdKG3GjoapoA8mxyjW6e3n4BFSFhR8rGPjZ9bYxDIzGEym5kQAH55L4fjk-oELJVmhDGkYvjYfnJwCYwHAAO5IQxQo4xOIiBLQeBIc7YPBEAQsTqyRCoMDmM6qdQaOTM8wODxHCAIQhQRDFIiLRncpyIPZHYAlRACAVgIXeILcABuaXwP0qNwZADpaFBijBafTpHZeR8JDBrAIJqNKudLhonI5HIgAORkpJgT1WhrKIMisU4KCmCw-D3OjkCTU0uyxQPBiRK2ALfBJlNRa3iJWEOA4fD6nBwDQCNWIeMEOy5kOEcUR8xRxAO-CVav4N0ez1Ck2aT2zOZtjtat1ehbIZhjQczYfmR3WTvj3vmKeFz115QQmOaIydmxbiRyTtZiT7ERHUVQEDFJCihthpMX0T54XO7ZaYbIHRSqlawgBC8OU4DkABGbhmFQYo5AAJkg1AAC85AAZiiDUx2cKsxwAakQMDE1EAB6AAqRA3xSUY6C-OAf10aVZTgUD5hAKcxjPcQoJgli2OKDjECg5CeOnPjREiRASKI19BULYtS3LD9qO-HRE0QIiiOlEC4IQ7iUIQoSABYc0vEQKMUmjkD1P8MGpdIgMQLSvVQT0dLkT1mBcgSkIxegNi2HZIm4LxUHAyC5AWJYokIkRSPIwV31UT9vz1TxGOYycRP4rjwsWHAsu81ZfM2MBtmfCSpNMmSixLMsBHM5K2FU9TNKY0KvO4iKcH0nz1mK7ZjNEIA)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following implementation if someone is looking for an implementation ready to go:

```ts
export function mapValues<T extends object, V>(object: T, mapper: (value: T[keyof T]) => V): {[K in keyof T]: V};

export function mapValues<
    T extends {[key in keyof T]?: N},
    M extends object,
    N extends PropertyKey | undefined | null | {}
>(object: T, mapping: M): {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends keyof M ? M[T[K]] : T[K]
};

export function mapValues<I extends Record<any, any>, R extends Record<keyof I, any>>(
    object: I,
    mapping: ((value: I[keyof I]) => R[keyof R]) | Partial<Record<I[keyof I], R[keyof R]>>
): R {
    const result: Partial<R> = {};

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object) as [keyof I, I[keyof I]][]) {
        if (typeof mapping === 'function') {
            result[key] = (mapping as (value: I[keyof I]) => R[keyof R])(value);

            continue;
        }

        result[key] = value in mapping ? mapping[value] : value;
    }

    return result as R;
}
```

Thanks, @jcalz!